# ¿Por qué un grupo de radio button genera siempre el mismo valor al hacer alert() con JavaScript en PHP?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo para generar un grupo de radiobutton:

```
<?php
include_once 'conexiones/conexion.php'; 

function obtenerIdTipoCompartido() {
GLOBAL $conexion;

try 
{
    $consulta=$conexion->prepare("SELECT idTipoCompartido, descripcionTipoCompartido FROM tipo_compartidos");
    $consulta->execute(); 
    $resultados=$consulta->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($consulta->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
        $idTipoCompartido= $value["idTipoCompartido"];
        $descripcionTipoCompartido= $value["descripcionTipoCompartido"];
        echo "<input type=
        'radio' 
        id='idTipoCompartido' 
        name='idTipoCompartido' 
        value=".$idTipoCompartido."
        onchange='compartirOpciones();'>".$descripcionTipoCompartido;

    }
}
catch (PDOExcepcion $e) 
{
    echo "Error".$e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

Quisiera mostrar el valor que tiene (1,2,3,4) mediante un evento `onclick`. Tengo el siguiente archivo JS:

```
function compartirOpciones () {
var opcion = document.getElementById("idTipoCompartido");
var areaCompartir = document.getElementById("areaCompartir");
alert (opcion);

switch (opcion) {

case 1: 
alert ("1");
if (opcion.checked) {
  var valor= document.getElementById('idTipoCompartido').value;
  alert(valor);
}

break;

case 2:
alert ("2");
break;

case 3:
alert ("3");
break;

case 4:
alert ("4");
break;

}
}
```

Pero me muestra unicamente 1,1,1,1, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**MALA MIA**: en lo posible utilizar Javascript puro.

Código que uso actualmente:

```
function compartirOpciones(elemento){
  var valor= elemento.value;
  var id = elemento.id;

  switch(valor) {

      case 1:
      alert(valor);
      alert(id);
      break;

      case 2:
       alert(valor);
      alert(id);
          break;

      case 3:
       alert(valor);
      alert(id);

      break;

      case 4:
       alert(valor);
      alert(id);
       break;

      default:
  }

}
```

No muestra el valor o el id

Comment: Porque les asignas **a todos el mismo id manualmente** aquí: `... echo "<input type=
        'radio' 
        id='idTipoCompartido' ...`

Comment: @A.Cedano , eso queria ver como cambiarlo, no recordaba cual de los dos campos (id , name) debe ser el mismo para que interectactuen como grupo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos puntualizaciones:

- La primera, es que nunca más de un elemento en el código HTML debería de usar el mismo ID ya que va a generar problemas. Si quieres que varios elementos tengan unos estilos concretos puedes usar clases en su lugar.
- Lo segundo, es que cuando tu haces clic sobre un elemento de la página puedes utilizar la palabra reservada `this` para hacer referencia al elemento que acabas de clickar y pasárselo a la función como parámetro.

Por lo tanto, no necesitarías utilizar mucho código para mostrar el valor que tiene cada radio button, simplemente pasar la referencia del elemento al que le estás haciendo clic como parámetro de la función y sacar su valor por pantalla.

Un pequeño ejemplo para que veas su funcionamiento:

```js
function compartirOpciones(elemento){
  alert(elemento.value);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="idTipoCompartido" onchange='compartirOpciones(this)'>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="idTipoCompartido" onchange='compartirOpciones(this)'>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

Si quieres usar un `switch` como el de tu ejemplo tendrías que poner comillas `""` a cada uno de tus `case` ya que `value` devuelve un valor de tipo texto.

Ejemplo:

```
switch(valor){
    case "1":
       //Tu código
       break; 
    case "2":
       ....
}
```

Comment: Como puedo generar algo asi: idTipoCompartido+phpvariable

Comment: @Victor-Random puedes obtener el valor usando sólo la etiqueta `name` de los radio por lo que la etiqueta `id` si sólo los quieres para eso, **no hace falta**. Como verás en la respuesta, tampoco tienes que agregar  el evento `onchange` a _todossss_ los radio. Revisa mi respuesta **editada** la parte **A**.

Comment: @Victor-Random ¿Que variable quieres sacar exactamente? Si lo que quieres es crear un id diferente para cada uno de los radiobutton podrías hacer  `id='idTipoCompartido".$idTipoCompartido."'` a la hora de generar los radiobutton.

Comment: Lo hice asi id='idTipoCompartido$idTipoCompartido'

Comment: @Victor-Random Te faltarían las comillas dobles para concatenarlo al string final.

Comment: Lo puse directo, ya que PHP permite reconocer las variables dentro de los string con comillas dobles :), si lo pongo como me dices no carga la varaible dentro del iD

Comment: @Victor-Random Tienes razón. Fallo mío. Bien visto :)

Comment: Añadire algo a la pregunta porque no se que hice mal

Comment: @Victor-Random ¿Has añadido la palabra this como parámetro de la función en cada uno de los radio button?

Comment: @FranciscoRomero sip, si hago el alert luego de declarar las variables funciona bien, muestra 1,2,3,4 idtipo1, idtipo2,idtipo3, idtipo4

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59643/discussion-between-francisco-romero-and-victor-random).

Answer (score 2):

## A. Con Javascript puro

Usando Javascript puro puedes obtener el valor de cualquiera de los radio seleccionados usando solo la etiqueta `name` que será la misma para todos. La función mostrada *escucha* los cambios de todos los radios incluidos en el formulario cuyo id es `myForm`.

Es una forma sencilla de hacerlo, sin tener que estar agregando el evento `onchange()` a todos los radios, y sin tener que agregarles `id`, a no ser que necesites por algún motivo identificarlos de forma unívoca.

```js
 var radios = document.forms["myForm"].elements["myRadio"];
      for(var i = 0, max = radios.length; i < max; i++) {
          radios[i].onclick = function() {
               alert(this.value);
      }
 }
```

```html
 <form id="myForm">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" >1</input>
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" >2</input>
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3" >3</input>
 </form>
```

## B. Con jQuery

Para obtener el valor del radio seleccionado.

Suponiendo que los radio tienen en la etiqueta `name` el valor `radioName` y que se encuentran en un formulario cuyo id es `myForm`, puedes hacerlo simplemente así:

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

```js
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
  alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val());
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Si no tienes un formulario, puedes asignar el listener al elemento `<body>` del DOM.

Ejemplo:

```js
$('body').on("change", "input[name='radioName']", function() {
  var $value= $("input[name='radioName']:checked").val();
  alert($value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
  <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
```

Comment: EL menos uno tampoco es mio :)

Comment: Creo que lo primero que hare, sera cambiar los IDs para que cada uno se llame asi idTipo1, idTipo2, idTipo3

Comment: @Victor-Random He agregado una solución usando JS puro. Gracias.

Comment: @Victor-Random si lo que quieres es sólo recuperar el valor del radio seleccionado, el `id` sobra. Como muestro en la respuesta **A**, usando Javascript puro puedes obtener el valor de cualquiera de los radio seleccionados usando solo la etiqueta `name` que será la misma para todos. La función _escucha_ los cambios de todos los radios incluidos en el formulario `myForm`.